# How to prevent spam in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spam-prevention

Does anyone know how to stop spam in rails? I've tried many solutions, which all has failed.

**I have tried:**

**Captcha:** I am currently not a fan of captcha since it interrupts when the user is signing up but upon putting captcha on signup page bots still managed to get passed it.

**Honeypot:** I've created a hidden field set the max character value to 0 and push the form -9999px off the screen and for some reason that does not stop the spam.

**askimet:** While this works well with wordpress it comes with a monthly fee so I am not interested in something like this.

Is there anyway to stop the spam bots in rails from signing up?

Comment: What kind of spam exactly?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Not sure what you're referring to when you say type of spam but spam bots that are signing up on my site, Im getting attacked and am not sure to stop it on the server lever or web app level.

Comment: Is it that they register, add comments, send email, whatever? There are milion types of spam and I guess one can use different methods to fight it.

Comment: Ok now I understand and they can register which is my biggest problem. How can I prevent them from registering? I have an email confirmation setup and they've seem to bypass that also.

Comment: Because they simply may not be bots. It's quite popular to hire guys from India to sit and type in captcha. BTW what type of captcha you use - reCaptcha?

Comment: Ok and yes i've used reCaptcha and that did not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, if recaptcha didn't stop it I belive it's not bots but some people clicking through (as long as recaptcha is still based on words that were unprocessable by OCR, not sure if this is a case)

Answer (score 7):

For a `honeypot` solution, you can use [invisible_captcha](https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha).

It works pretty nice for small and medium sites, with a simple and configurable approach.

More or less:

In your form:

```
<%= form_tag(create_topic_path) %>
  <%= invisible_captcha %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  invisible_captcha only: [:create, :update]
  ...
end
```

Comment: does this gem catch spams most of the time ?

Comment: It worked for me in multiple small and medium (in terms of traffic) apps. And it seems for other people too: ~80k downloads according RubyGems, https://medium.com/withbetterco/dealing-with-spam-form-submissions-in-rails-b5b477ae7dcf, https://github.com/markets/invisible_captcha/network/dependents.

Answer (score 2):

Aggressive Spam Bots are using (most of the times) the same tld or selected names, strings or numbers.

You can try [Filters Spam](https://github.com/resolve/filters_spam) to filter out Words etc. you don't like in your App.

And if you have a Really Big Problem with Spam just go with [Rakismet (Ruby Akismet)](https://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet), for only 4.99/Month. I dont think this is to much to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Try projecthoneypot gem https://github.com/cmaxw/project-honeypot. It uses Http:BL service which maintains a list of suspicious IP's.Check this out http://www.projecthoneypot.org/httpbl.php